# How to fetch data from web page into google spread sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to pull data(not html only) from crbug.com list(or from any web data for ex: data showing in asp:gridview and want to push in google spreadsheet) and push into google spreadsheet..

In example https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app pull tweet from twitter and pushing into sheet, I also wantdo the same but not from tweeter.

Comment: Not HTML only? What you'd like to pull? Anyhow, you can only pull more if the site builds it, as a REST or something. Anyway, you're question is too vague and badly constructed, doens't seem like you put much research nor time into it.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list please go through the url, you fill find the entire dynamic table with ton of data, actually that particular data i have to pull into one google spreadsheet.

Comment: Show what you tried. The official docs show how to write to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case there is a link to a CSV of the bugs.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/csv

It can be fetched and parsed:

```
    var responseData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/csv').getBlob();
    var parsedBugs  = Utilities.parseCsv(responseData.getDataAsString());
    Logger.log(parsedBugs);
```

parsedBugs will be an array[][] of the bugs from that site.